# Using the Advanced Filter in Excel to filter a long list by using a shoter list

Tags: excel, excel-2010

I have an excel document with all of the cities in Missouri with their corresponding zipcode and county. Out of the 1000+ items on the list only about 500 pertain to me. I have a list of the cities I need. I have tried using the advanced filter to filter out the unwanted results, but was unsuccessful. I have been at this for hours and cant seem to get it to work. Can someone please help me figure this out?

[image: Long List]

[image: Criteria]

Comment: Use a vlookup and then filter by non-blanks?

Comment: You cannot be using the [Advanced Filter](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Video-Advanced-filter-details-BBD0CB0A-8F90-43DF-BF77-6AD3774DC420) corrrectly. Click the supplied link for a quick tutorial video.

Comment: So you only want to see the items on the first tab that exist on the second tab?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a VLOOKUP in the first sheet to find the matches, then sort out the mismatches.  Here are the steps

1. In your My Cities sheet, select all of the cities and name the range MyCities by typing it into the name box right above column A
2. In the sheet with the zip codes, in cell D2, enter formula

   =IFERROR(VLOOKUP(C2,MyCities,1,FALSE),0)
3. Copy that formula in column D to the bottom of your data
4. In Cell D1 type in Match (so your sort will see the data set properly)
5. Sort on column D...the 0's should be the unwanted

Answer (score 0):

I've had what looks like this very same problem for another state.  My solution wasn't so high-tech as using any fancy Excel functions.  The reason was that there may be no query-able patterns of names, and no patterns of zip codes. Zip codes, as you know, cross city and county and other political boundaries, so they can be a challenge. There were only patterns of counties. First I assigned names and numbers to counties, in alphabetical order.  If I wanted a certain county, I simply query or sort and select by the county number (the name would work, but the number was easier).  If I wanted a query by city, I could sort on the city name and select from that.  Anything beyond that required specific coding.  For example, if I wanted contiguous counties, I had to create a manual code for contiguousness.  If I wanted only certain cities in a group I had to manually code those cities.  In any case, I'd sort on whatever was the appropriate code and select the area of the list that was needed.  If you already have a list of zip codes or counties or something like that, then it might be faster and better better to put your two tables into MS Access and do a join query.